# Theano deconvolution layer

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network

wanting to implement a deconv layer in theano but I don't think it's working right. Any suggestions?

```
class ConvTransposeLayer(object):
    """
    Deconv layer
    Built from the following literatures:
    - http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html
    - A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285v1.pdf)
    - Lasagne deconv layer (https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/layers/conv.py)

    Performs the backward pass of a 2D convolution (also called transposed
    convolution, fractionally-strided convolution or deconvolution in the
    literature) on its input and optionally applies an elementwise nonlinearity
    """
    def __init__(self, input, output_shape, filters, filter_shape, activation=None, border_mode='valid', stride=(2,2), filter_flip=False):

        # track input
        self.input = input

        # --------------------
        # Deconv is done by swapping the forward and backward passes of a convolution.
        # this is implemented as the gradients with respect to the original layer with the
        # convolutions
        deconv_op = AbstractConv2d_gradInputs(
            imshp=output_shape,
            kshp=filter_shape,
            border_mode=border_mode,
            subsample=stride,
            filter_flip=filter_flip
        )

        output = deconv_op(filters, input, output_shape[2:])

        # --------------------
        # Run through activation function
        if activation is None:
            self.output = output
        else:
            self.output = activation(output)
```

It is used like:

```
conv_layer_3_encoder = Layers.ConvLayer(
        self.rng,
        input=droput_conv_2.output,
        input_filter_count=96,
        output_filter_count=192,
        filter_shape=(3, 3),
        stride=(2, 2),
        activation=activations.relu
    )

    droput_conv_3 = Layers.DropoutLayer(
        self.rng,
        input=conv_layer_3_encoder.output,
        p=0.2
    )

    # -----------------
    # DECODING LAYER 3 + DROPOUT
    deconv_layer_3_decoder = Layers.ConvTransposeLayer(input=droput_conv_3.output,
                                                       output_shape=image_shape_layer_3,
                                                       filters=conv_layer_3_encoder.filters,
                                                       filter_shape=filter_shape_layer_3,
                                                       activation=activations.relu)

    droput_deconv_3 = Layers.DropoutLayer(
        self.rng,
        input=deconv_layer_3_decoder.output,
        p=0.2
    )
```

Comment: I was trying to implement the same function here. what I found that it is applied to 2D kernel only. did you find a way how can we apply the deconv by using kernel with multiple channels ?